# Retrieve data from a custom object via lookup formula

Tags: custom-object, formula-field

I'm trying to populate a field on the leads object with data from a custom object via a formula field. I'm pretty close to getting the right stuff there, but I am getting a little hung up and wondering if anyone out there has a solution.

I'm retrieving the data via VLOOKUP, but I keep getting syntax errors. I have create the relationship with the leads and custom object, which is labeled Market__c. The field i am trying to retrieve data from is a picklist and it keeps telling me that "Error: Field Market_Status__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions." The picklist only has 2 options, open and closed. Thats a pretty obvious explanation as to why it won't work, but I am looking for the value of the field, not the picklist values.

In the code below, Market__c is the field from the lead that I am passing over as the value to search for in the Market Object. It should match the field Name in the Market object and return the value of the field Market_Status__c associated with the matched Name.(For instance Market__c = Miami: FL. it matches the name in the Market object and finds whether the market is open or closed. That data is contained in the Market_Status__c field.)

```
AND(LEN(Market__c) > 0,
VLOOKUP( Market_Statuses__r.Market_Status__c ,  Market_Statuses__r.Name , Market__c ))
```

Anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this might help:

`AND(LEN(Market__c) > 0,
VLOOKUP( TEXT(Market_Statuses__r.Market_Status__c) ,  Market_Statuses__r.Name , Market__c ))`

Comment: You understood perfectly! however I am getting a different error now. "Error: Function VLOOKUP may not be used in this type of formula". It seems i am using VLOOKUP correctly, but it's still throwing errors.

Comment: According to the salesforce [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#VLOOKUP) VLOOKUP may only be used in validation rules. So you cannot use it in a formula field.
Is 'Market__c' a text field on the 'Lead' object - or is it a relationship to your custom object?

Comment: Is there any way to use this method to retrieve the value? Market__c is a text field that will contain the market that the customer is in.

Comment: According to the docs, no. Do you have a direct link between your lead and your Market object?

Comment: Ok, back to the drawing board. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it!